# D3 scroll/pan/zoom not working

Tags: github, d3.js

I am working with d3 example available at

http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/area-gradient.html

all the js and css files are in place,

I am getting the following error

Property 'x' of object [object Object] is not a function i get why this error occurs its because we call x(0) function but seems its there is no such function, but how come the example is working on the first place with the same code?

Or am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: You haven't copied all the files you need then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `draw()` function, the axis are built and the `x` and `y` scales applied to them. Thus the call to `x(0)` (unless it relates to the `x` accessor for the `line` and `area` generators which are also being called...I suspect not but the error is not very clear). In any case, more important to what is going on, note that this example is relatively old and is using d3 library versions built at that time. I have tried to use the new version and it does not work. So, **without changing code**, you pretty much need to use these libraries. Also, make sure to call the script in the right place inside the html body.

I have created a functional [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/8q4bzNKnqNOJo5CQbkZ3?p=preview) that you can fork and experiment with.

Comment: & sry very much for the delayed reply